# Thinking of getting rid of my laptop

Tags: ipad, airport, appletv

Thinking of getting rid of my laptop and using my iPhone / iPad / Apple TV 4 to access files on the PC now by getting a 2TB Time Capsule.

Will I be able to edit photos, view and edit spreadsheets, etc. on the TB with an iPad Pro as if it is a hard drive? Assuming this is done on my home WiFi network only.

Also, I have a large amount of movies and music in my iTunes library, without loading all that on the TB, will I be able to access those as well?  Assuming this is done on my home WiFi network only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do all the things you asked, provided you have the correct apps on the iPad.  It's easier to do these things if you keep your docs in iCloud instead of the network share, though.

For instance, I have the MS Excel app and I store all my spreadsheets on a network share or on iCloud.  I can do almost everything I need to do thru the app.  I also have **Emby** and **Plex** apps to watch all my movies on the network share.